# Putting scale bar labels below scale bar in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, scale, scale-bar

I added two scale elements to my map composition. For layout harmonisation, I want the ticks and the label text below the scale bar.

Standard is this:
[image: This is what I get.]

What I want is this (manually changed in the image):
[image]

Is there an option in QGIS for this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think there's an option yet which allows you to put the units below the scalebar. An alternative could be to:

1. Modify your current scalebar and set its `Font colour` to match the background colour:

   ```
   Item Properties > Fonts and colours > Font colour
   ```
2. Copy your scalebar and paste it directly below your original scalebar. Then set its `Font colour` to black and its `Line colour` to transparent:

   ```
   Item Properties > Fonts and colours > Font colour
                                       > Line colour
   ```
3. You can then select your scalebars and **group** them, allowing you to move them easily as if they were one:

   [image: Scalebars]

Comment: Maybe it is not possible yet doing that because the `Labels margin` field from the `Display` Menu doesn't accept negative values. However, nice workaround!

Comment: I've used this trick in the past to do two-sided scales (e.g. Nautical miles on one side, Km on the other.) Always need 3 scales for that, one just for labelling downticks, one with uptick scale and labels and one to show downticks only. Messy, but it does the job...

Comment: @mgri - If it did accept negative values (which I'm hoping is a simple fix) then that would be very nice indeed =)

Comment: @StevenKay - Messy and can be annoying when having to alter the segments for the different scale units to match your requirement :)

Comment: Ok, this convinced me in practice even more than @Swod's hack.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it is possible within qgis print composer.

However you can play with a template file to make it work. You can set the distance between the text labels and the scale bar in:

*Item properties > Display > Labels margin*.

Unfortunately you can't set it to a negative value (= scale bar above the text) within the print composer.

But you can within a template file. Create an empty print composition and within it a scale bar, with the right style etc. Save this as template ("Composer > Save as template"). This will create a *.qpt file. Open this file with a text editor and search for the term "labelBarSpace" and set it to a negative value e.g. -10. (Depending on you font size you'll have to adjust this value.)
Within the qgis print composer add this template (Composer > Add Items from Template) and it'll show the numbers below the scale bar.

As long as you don't touch the *Item properties > Display > Labels margin* - settings it will stay this way. This worked for me with QGIS 2.18.

Comment: Weird that, obviously, not many people want to have the labels below the line - but your hack is neat. I'm going to give it a shot, even though this means creating multiple templates for different formats (i.e. A0 plots and A4 printouts).