# Dual-unit scale bar using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, scale-bar

I would like to create a scale bar for a map displaying a coral atoll. Ideally, showing two different measurements with kilometers being on the top division and nautical miles on the bottom division of the scale bar.

I paused to think whether this is logical and decided that it may fit nicely because I am displaying a raised atoll with surrounding reef sites for monitoring purposes. Therefore, it may be important as areas of interest are within a water body and for say navigational purposes such as a skipper wanting to know the nautical miles to each site rather than kilometers (I know she/he could convert them by head).

Is this at all possible in QGIS? I have read that it can be done in ArcGIS http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011784

Open to your views and suggestions.

What I am trying to achieve:

[image: what I am trying to achieve]

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Beaver! I would suggest creating **two** scalebars and placing them on top of the other. Then select and _group_ them so that they can be moved as if they were one scalebar. To create a scalebar with the labels below it, you can have a look at this post: [Putting scale bar labels below scale bar in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238244/putting-scale-bar-labels-below-scale-bar-in-qgis)

Comment: Agree with @Joseph. This is the most forward approach to achive this now. For easier matching two scalebars, you can copy and paste the first one and with enabled *Smart guidlines* (*View* menu) move the copy over the original to match. Then adjust the properities and group.

Comment: Duly noted, thank you both Joseph and Oto Kaláb for swift responses.

Comment: Likely to be an enhancement in QGIS 3.0x as the composer is getting a rebuild. see the progress https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/milestone/7

Comment: @Joseph please consider posting your comment as an answer

Comment: @Mapperz that's the documentation roadmap/milestones - nothing to do with the actual QGIS 3.0 plans

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think there's a few steps involved and you may need **three** scalebars (instead of the two in my previous comment).

---

1. Create your first scalebar showing kilometers:

   [image: kilometers scalebar]

---

2. Create your second scalebar showing nautical miles:

   [image: Nautical miles scalebar]

---

3. Select the nautical mile scalebar and copy/paste it below (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> will do, thanks to [@Oto Kaláb](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/36001/oto-kal%c3%a1b) for this very useful tip!):

   [image: Copied scalebar]

---

4. Modify the original nautical scalebar and set its `Font colour` to match the background colour:

   ```
   Item Properties > Fonts and colours > Font colour
   ```

---

5. Then modify the copied scalebar and set its `Font colour` to black and its `Line colour` to transparent:

   ```
   Item Properties > Fonts and colours > Font colour
                                       > Line colour
   ```

   [image: Colour settings]

---

6. Align both nautical scalebars so that the numbers are below the ticks. Then select both these nautical scalebars and **group** them:

   [image: Group items]

---

7. Select the kilometer scalebar and **raise** it (this is needed for the next step):

   [image: Raise]

---

8. Select and align the grouped nautical scalebars over the kilometer scalebar so that the line overlaps. The **raise** setting avoids little artifacts such as white gaps from showing. You can change the X and Y positions for the grouped nautical scalebars from the `Position and size` properties to align it perfectly:

   ```
   Item Properties > Position and size
   ```

---

9. **Finally**, select the grouped nautical scalebars and the kilometer scalebar and group these. Now, hopefully, you should have a dual-unit scalebar:

   [image: Result]

Comment: done it this way before and it worked well - thanks for reminding me :)

Comment: @StevenKay - Yes, I just remembered you [mentioned it before](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238244/putting-scale-bar-labels-below-scale-bar-in-qgis/238248#comment371543_238248) :). Hopefully QGIS 3.0 will have nicer and easier features to use =)

Comment: @Joseph I like your way of working this out, my scale bars have never looked better. One of them days where I was mapped out but now I'm glad I asked this question and hopefully this helps others too.

Comment: @Beaver - Glad you got it working! I like to think that _all_ questions asked here helps someone :)